# How to make an Analytics segment that is "Everyone not in this other segment"

Tags: google-analytics, advanced-segments

I have a segment I've created in Google Analytics (called it "segment X"), and now I want to make a new segment that is "Everyone not included in segment X" -- how can I do that?

(BTW segments are so cool!!)

Comment: It will depend on the definition of segment X - unfortunately you can't define a segment based on another segment. You'll have to define a second segment with opposite conditions from X (which we can help you with if you give details of X!).

Comment: GA doesn't allow you to use existed segments to create new ones; the solution would be to create new segment basis reverse conditions like mentioned by @Reve

Comment: Thank you both. @Reve if you can add your comment as an answer, I'm happy to accept it as the official answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it would be really nice if Google Analytics allowed you to base a segment definition on another segment, it does not. To create a "everything except segment X" segment you'll need to create a segment Y that uses the negation of the conditions in segment X.

Potentially useful reminder: the negation of `A and B` is `not-A or not-B` and the negation of `A or B` is `not-A and not-B`. Segments **are** cool - have fun!